# Starling, Atlas Texture "Texture cannot be null"

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, textures, starling-framework

I develop a Flex/Starling game and i want use Atlas Texture to optimise all sprite call.
My problem is that i use a clear and simple code, with basic ressources and i cant run, i get an Argument Error, Texture cannot be null.
I understand that the .getTexture method find nothing, but i dont see how fix this problem, my code:

```
[Embed(source = "Atlas_bg/AtlasBackground.xml")]
public var AtlasXml:Class

[Embed(source = "Atlas_bg/AtlasBackground.png")]
public var AtlasPng:Class


// create atlas
var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new AtlasPng());
var xml:XML = XML(new AtlasXml());
var atlas:TextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(texture, xml);
// display a sub-texture
var objsTexture:Texture = atlas.getTexture("star_0");// ne trouve rien
var objsImage:Image = new Image(objsTexture);
addChildAt(objsImage, 0.6);
objsImage.x = 200;
objsImage.y = 200;
```

XML content:

```
<TextureAtlas imagePath="AtlasBackground.png">
    <SubTexture name="star_0" x="2" y="2" width="20" height="20"/>
    <SubTexture name="star_1" x="2" y="24" width="20" height="20"/>
</TextureAtlas>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are not embedding the **Atlas XML file** correctly and therefore the information of the **TextureAtlas** can't be properly read.

Try the following two additions:

1. Add the **mimeType** attribute in your `Embed` metatag:

   [Embed(source = "Atlas_bg/AtlasBackground.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
   public var AtlasXml:Class;
2. Add the following line at the beginning of your XML file:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

After this, **clean your project** a couple of times to get rid of previous builds with the incorrect embedded file and build your project again. Everything should be working now.

Comment: Thx, i'll try your tips, and i tell asap if that fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's where the `ArgumentError` is pointing at? I noticed you're using a `Number` instead of an `int` for the `addChildAt()` function in the 2nd parameter.

Try swapping it to this and see if that fixes things:

```
addChild(objsImage);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's weird (might be a typo) but it's not the source of the error. addChildAt expects an int parameter so the Number passed to it is truncated to its integer part (in this case, 0) and it should work.